# ASP.NET Core 3.1 web API (versioning) and Swagger UI fails due to MvcJsonOptions once published to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-3.0

I have recently migrated the ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API project to ASP.NET Core 3.1 Preview 3. I use the URL based API versioning and Swagger UI 3.0 (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.0.0-rc4). As soon as the web API is published on Azure I get below error (I am not sure if Swagger UI has anything to do with it but...)

**System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compare two elements in the array.
---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json,**

Referring to similar issues in Git Hub my understanding was the issue is fixed with preview 3 and indeed after installing the SDK 3.1.100-preview3, ***I do not see this issue on my local dev machine.***

**Local DEV Machine** (Everything works correctly...)

[image]

**Published to Azure Web Services**

Since the framework is not yet supported to I am publishing it as a Self-Contained web api application. Publish is successful, but I get the following issue during runtime... How do I resolve this issue?

[image]

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compare two elements in the array.
 ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
   at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.get_Signature()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.GetParametersNoCopy()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.GetParameters()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.<>c.<CreateConstructorCallSite>b__16_1(ConstructorInfo a, ConstructorInfo b)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.SwapIfGreater(T[] keys, Comparison`1 comparer, Int32 a, Int32 b)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.IntroSort(T[] keys, Int32 lo, Int32 hi, Int32 depthLimit, Comparison`1 comparer)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.IntrospectiveSort(T[] keys, Int32 left, Int32 length, Comparison`1 comparer)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, Comparison`1 comparer)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, Comparison`1 comparer)
   at System.Array.Sort[T](T[] array, Comparison`1 comparison)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<GetCallSite>b__0(Type type)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<GetCallSite>b__0(Type type)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<GetCallSite>b__0(Type type)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type middleware)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , HttpContext , IServiceProvider )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_1.<UseMiddleware>b__2(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Have you tried deploying with the "Remove additional files at destination" setting? I've had odd issues sometimes when I had some old DLLs in there.

Comment: @juunas: Yes my publish profile has Remove additional files at destination turned ON always. But other than this, is there any other way to completely delete the previously published web app 2.2 on Azure and start afresh publish with 3.1?

Comment: I just updated my api to 3.1 and i used the v5.0.0-rc4 and i was able to remove this same error

Comment: You can probably delete the files on the server through Kudu @Ameya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For ASP.NET Core 3.0 (and 3.1), make sure you target `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` version 5.0 at least (not RC version). This should fix that particular problem.

The reason why you experience the issue is that Swagger previously depended on `MvcJsonOptions` which was part of the ASP.NET Core framework. Swagger loads and tries to find that class, and it doesn't exist. But now since the ASP.NET Core framework uses System.Text.Json rather than Newtonsoft.Json that causes the compile error.

And on the same topic I suggest you [read this here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#systemtextjson-stj-vs-newtonsoft), which explains how to opt-in if you still want to continue use Newtonsoft.Json.

Generally speaking there have been some breaking changes for Swagger implementation. Here's good documentation on [what is breaking in 4.0](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/releases/tag/v4.0.0) and [what is breaking in 5.0](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/releases/tag/v5.0.0).

Comment: Adding a comment for issues after ugrading NSwag or NSwag.MsBuild as well as Swashbuckle.  If you get an error about unable to locate `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` version 5.0.0.0, even after adding it to both projects, you need to follow the link in this comment about enabling Newtonsoft Support in the project that NSwag is generating from.

Comment: There is no link in your comment @TJL?

Comment: Sorry, it was the first link in your answer - [this one](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#systemtextjson-stj-vs-newtonsoft).  It took me a long google road to get to this answer and this solved a problem with my nswag build.