# While updating project to .NET CORE 3.1 is giving error Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

While upgrading project to .NET CORE 3.1, I am facing error "'Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=3.1.25.0"

Steps tried to resolve:

1. Upgraded Swashbuckle.AspNetCore to 5.0.0 (Still not working).
2. Removed DLL Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json as mentioned that support for this DLL is removed in CORE 3.1 (Still not working).

Basically I am getting issue in CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run() --> So here in Build() it's throwing an error.

Comment: Can you please add a [mre]?

Comment: From [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/325) , we can see MvcJsonOptions was removed in .NET Core 3.0,  so you're getting the error . Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59037170/asp-net-core-3-1-web-api-versioning-and-swagger-ui-fails-due-to-mvcjsonoptions) and try.

Comment: @GuruStron When I start my project (which is in .NET CORE 3.1) on runtime only it shows error "Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=3.1.25.0" in line CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run()

Comment: @QingGuo Yes it was removed in 3.0. I upgraded the Swashbuckle but no luck and tried other options as well but still showing an error.